# How can I install an older version of the iPhone SDK (v3.1.2) to work with the latest GM?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I installed the latest GM of the iPhone SDK and now I can't build and compile many of the example projects on the Apple iPhone dev site.  When I load them, the configuration bar says "Base SDK is missing."  It appears the example project I'm trying to build (QuartzDemo) is trying to build against the v3.1.2 SDK.  How can I install an older version of the iPhone SDK that works with the latest GM?  Or how can I get this project to build with the current GM version of the SDK?

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the base SDK of the project to 4.0; 3.1.3 and earlier aren't supported.

Comment: But you can also set the target version to 3.1.x (or earlier) if you need the build to work on older devices.  You just do not get a 3.1.x simulator anymore.